# Java program using gnome-java will not compile

Tags: java, gtk, javac, gnome

When trying to compile this small Java program to make use of the Notifier class from java-gnome (built from latest bzr branch):

```
import org.gnome.notify;


class Notifier {

public void Main(String[] args) {

        Notification n = new Notification("Test notification", "Blah.", "");
        n.setTimeout(2000);
        n.show();

    }
}
```

I get the following output when compiling with:

```
$ javac -cp .:/usr/local/share/java/gtk-4.0.jar Notifier.java 

Notifier.java:1: package org.gnome does not exist
import org.gnome.notify;
            ^
Notifier.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Notification
location: class Notifier
Notification n = new Notification("Test notification", "Blah.", "");
    ^
Notifier.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Notification
location: class Notifier
Notification n = new Notification("Test notification", "Blah.", "");
                         ^
3 errors
```

/usr/local/share/java/gtk-4.0.jar definately exists at that location and does contain the used classes. What is wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you follow Rich (who is totally right), your application won't compile. Here goes minimalistic example:

```
import org.gnome.gdk.Event;
import org.gnome.gtk.Gtk;
import org.gnome.gtk.Widget;
import org.gnome.gtk.Window;
import org.gnome.notify.Notification;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // gtk init
        Gtk.init(args);

        // create main window
        final Window window = new Window();

        // connect delete event to main window
        window.connect(new Window.DeleteEvent() {
            public boolean onDeleteEvent(Widget source, Event event) {
                Gtk.mainQuit();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // create notification
        Notification notification = new Notification("foo", "bar", "baz", window);

        // show widgets
        window.show();
        notification.show();

        // main loop
        Gtk.main();
    }
}
```

Compiler line:

```
javac -classpath $CLASSPATH:/usr/local/share/java/gtk-4.0.jar Main.java
```

Comment: Thanks, guys. Since my program was cli, I infact only needed Gtk.init(args) and import org.gnome.gtk.Gtk, but its good to know for proper GTK apps in the future.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my reply btw.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this is just a typo in your question, but the import line should read:

```
import org.gnome.notify.*;
```

Note the trailing asterisk.

Also, your `main` method should be static.